# Get a Session value from my MVC app into my Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This isn't the standard, so please read before marking duplicate.

In our MVC app at the top of our `_Layout.cshtml`, we load our scripts like this:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```

At the bottom of `_Layout.cshtml` we have this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

For reasons outside of my control we must have the defer on that. :(

This bundle includes the jquery files. One of the other files is called `Script.js`, which gets loaded after jQuery, and has a function called `setCollapse(collapse)`.

It looks like this:

```
function setCollapse(collapse) {
    debugger;
    alert(collapse);
    if (collapse == 'False') {
        $('.collapse').collapse("show");
    } else {
        $('.collapse').collapse();
    }
}
```

I would like to use a Session value with that javascript function on my MVC View load like this:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            debugger;
            var collapse = '@Session["Collapse"].ToString()';
            setCollapse(collapse);
        });
    </script>
}
```

But I continue to get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How can I get my Session value to get passed into my javascript/jQuery when the page loads?

Comment: have you loaded your jquery scripts correctly?

Comment: Yes, all my other jQuery code works okay. The thing is, with the defer, any javascript in the view gets run before the jQuery is loaded. My script.js file gets loaded after jQuery, but I'm not sure how to get the Session value into script.js.

Comment: Try without defer. Your code should work as long as you include jQuery in your page before using it.

Comment: Quote from [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) - "The defer attribute is only for external scripts (should only be used if the src attribute is present)." So, you are using the defer attribute incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I worked it out. Of course it was simpler than I figured.

In our MVC app at the top of our `_Layout.cshtml` I do this:

```
<script>
    var collapse = '@Session["Collapse"].ToString()';
</script>
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```

The `RenderFormat` loads jQuery and my `script.js` file.

Then in my script.js I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //....

    // Global collapse value
    if (collapse == 'False') {
        $('.collapse').collapse("show");
    } else {
        $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

before the closing body tag in you layout file. As long as your jquery is loaded before that it should just work.

**Edit**

Add this in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$ = (function () {
        var q = [], f = function (cb) {
            q.push(cb);
        };
        f.attachReady = function ($) {
            $(function () {
                $.each(q, function (i, f) {
                    f();
                });
                q.length = 0; // clear it, just in case
            });
            return $;
        }
        return f;
    })();
</script>
```

And then the following before the end of the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $ = $.attachReady(jQuery);
</script>
```

This would defer all the jquery dependent code and run them once jquery is loaded.

**Edit 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $ = $.attachReady(jQuery);
</script>
```

This should be the last thing before the end of the body tag.

Comment: I have that. Because of the `defer`, the `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` runs before jQuery is loaded. Even if I put defer in the scripts for the `RenderSection` they run before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Should I put that `$.noConflict();` part before or after the `@RenderSection("scripts", false)`?

Comment: I get this: Uncaught ReferenceError: setCollapse is not defined(anonymous function); Uncaught TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function

Comment: The problem here is the defer keyword which is strictly for external scripts. But yours is not external script. What you should do is remove the defer keyword, put your jquery before the end of the body tag and then include the noconflict bit below the jquery. This way your jquery will be loaded at the end of the page load anyway .